# Torah provision for Jews who can not be in Israel during feasts?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, chagim-holidays, golus-exile

Are there any exceptions in the Torah to keeping the feasts when you are not able to be in Israel? For example, through captivity or through choice (living in a different part of the world).

- Passover (Pesach) - Nisan 14-15
- Unleavened Bread (Chag Hamatzot) - Nisan 15-22
- First Fruits (Yom habikkurim) - Nisan 16-17
- Pentecost (Shavu'ot) - Sivan 6-7
- Trumpets (Yom Teru'ah) - Tishri 1
- Atonement (Yom Kippur) - Tishri 10
- Tabernacles (Sukkot) - Tishri 15-22

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Could you [edit] to clarify what feasts you're referring to?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Are you asking about the celebration, or the קרבנות (sacrificial offerings)? ....we still celebrate the holidays, in the Diaspora, but we can't bring offerings without the Temple.

Comment: Some of the holidays require physical attendance at a certain location (like the temple), so that was what I was referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jews around the world celebrate the holidays, or "feasts" as you call them. However, there are some differences in observances.

Outside of Israel, an extra day is added to each holiday. This means that while the Israeli Pesach is 7 days, it's 8 elsewhere. Also, due to the formation, in Israel it's 1-5-1, where the ones are full holidays (with restrictions on work), and in the middle is "chol hamoed" -- fewer restrictions. Outside of Israel, it's 2-4-2, with an extra holy day added to both parts.

Yom Kippur is only one day worldwide, because it's too hard to fast for two days.

Rosh Hashanah is also two days even in Israel, due to ancient tradition.

This applies to the modern age. When the Temple stood, it was a positive commandment to go up to the Temple on Pesach, Shavuot, and Sukkot. Obviously, not everyone made it.

Also, Erev Pesach (14th of Nisan) there was the *korban Pesach* (Pascal lamb) to be brought. For those unable to make it (due to distance or ritual impurity), they could make it up one month later, on the 14th of Iyyar (Pesach Sheini).

Hope this addresses your concerns.

Comment: @msh Which of these provisions is ftom the Torah?

Comment: @DoubleAA all of them. Am I missing something?

Comment: @msh Yom Tov Sheni is rabbinic as you know...

Comment: @DoubleAA and rabbinic enactments are part of the Torah, as you know.

Comment: @msh210 You're playing semantic games with me, as you know.

Comment: @DoubleAA, you started. Or, if you prefer, Scimonster did. All I did was approve of the answer. Let's continue this in [Bam](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/468) if anywhere, shall we?